# Modal does not display inputs values

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, modal-dialog

So I have a basic modal with a input. This modal receives a response, but my problem is that when I call the modal the display does not assume the values that it haf to in the input field.

My modal:

```
@model Response
<div class="modal fade" id="MyModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form>
                <input asp-for="Description" type="text" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer" id="buttons-box">
            <button type="button" class="btn default" data-dismiss="modal">Close Modal</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Entity:

```
public class Response
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Jquery Code that calls controler action:

```
function showModal(id) {
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url: "/Controller/Get/" + id,
    success: function (res) {
        $("#Description").val(res.description);
        $("#MyModal").modal('show');
    }
})}
```

My Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id)
    {
       var result = await _Service.FindByIdAsync(id);

       return Json(result);
    }
```

My response is coming correct but that display does not happen. Please help...

Comment: Hi, it works fine in my project. I think you need debug your code and check if the `result` contains value.

Comment: It contains, I checked, but my problem is that it does not change the val of the input

Comment: Could you pls check the generated html code of your modal? Does it generate like below  `<input id="Description" name="Description" />`? You can F12 in browser and check the `Elements` panel to check the html code.

Answer (score 0):

Check the submitted url.

Looks like you did not send the data to the Controller and are waiting for a response
The ajax code should be as follows

```
    function showModal(id) {
    $.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url: "/Controller/Get/" + id,
    data: {
    'id': id,
    },
    success: function (res) {
    $("#Description").val(res.description);
    $("#MyModal").modal('show');
   }
```

})}

Comment: The response is comming properly, but it does not goes to the value of the input